# res.cookie is not setting cookie in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, cookies

In development, I have a simple login page running on localhost (`http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html`) and a minimal express server running on `http://localhost:3003`

I can see that the server is showing my `access_token` being sent in response headers but chrome browser is not setting it.

[image: response headers are set]

The application panel does not show any cookies being set.
[image: Application panel is empty]

Here is my server:

```js
const express = require("express");

const cors = require("cors");

const JWT = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const { json } = require("express");

const users = require("../users.json");

const SECRET = "1234";

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5500",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());



app.post("/auth/login", (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // add pseudo validation
  if (email !== "********" && password !== "asdfasdf") {
    res.status(403);
    throw new Error("Bad user credentials");
  }

  const token = JWT.sign({ email }, SECRET);
  // console.log("token values:", token);

  res.cookie("access_token", token, {
    maxAge: 3600,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    sameSite: "lax",
  });

  res.status(200).json({
    foo: "bar",
  });
});
```

On the frontend I am using fetch:

```js
const loginForm = document.querySelector("#loginForm");

loginForm.addEventListener("submit", login);

function login(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const email = evt.target.email.value;
  const password = evt.target.psw.value;
  evt.target.reset();

  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  headers.append("Accept", "application/json");

  return fetch("http://localhost:3003/auth/login", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include", // Don't forget to specify this if you need cookies
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
  }).then(
    (res) => {
      console.log(res);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
```

I have tried multiple solutions posted for this same issue on SO:

1. Adding `mode: "cors"` and `credentials: "include"` on the frontend
2. Setting `httpOnly` to `false`, `secure` to `false` and also `sameSite: "lax"` on server to get past the new samesite chrome browser restrictions

And still nothing works! what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the browser console display messages about third-party cookies being blocked?

Comment: nope. It doesn't give me any errors

Comment: Hover over the "info" icon next to `access_token` in the "response cookies" view.

Comment: I got it working now @HeikoTheißen. See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh God!! **localhost !== http://127.0.0.1**

I had to change my fetch call to:

```js
return fetch("http://http://127.0.0.1::3003/auth/login", { //<== this is the main change
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include", // Don't forget to specify this if you need cookies
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
  }).then(
    (res) => {
      console.log(res);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
```

Cookies get set now. Special thanks to https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1553#issuecomment-477761247

Comment: I'd  use `headers.set("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa(\`${email}:${password}\`))` at least instead of sending the email and password in a json body

Comment: same case I used axios withCredentials property now its working on frontend but express server is still not saving the cookie or receiving it, can anyone explain, Thank you